# FFMPEG save udp stream to mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, udp

I'm facing some trouble when using ffmpeg to save an udp stream into a mp4 file. When receiving and playing with ffplay by this command

`ffplay -i udp://127.0.0.1:10000`

everything is ok, but when I save to mp4 file with this command

`ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:10000 -vcodec libx264 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 20 test.mp4`

the created mp4 file has only 15 secs length but my streaming was 1 min. I found a solution

`ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:10000 -r 20 -filter:v "setpts=PTS*0.25" -vcodec libx264 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4`

by using `setpts` video filter, but video's length still wasn't same as the stream.
My udp stream's properties, get by using ffprobe:

```
[STREAM]                                          
index=0                                           
codec_name=h264                                   
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 
profile=High 4:4:4 Predictive                     
codec_type=video                                  
codec_time_base=1/40                              
codec_tag_string=[27][0][0][0]                    
codec_tag=0x001b                                  
width=1280                                        
height=720                                        
coded_width=1280                                  
coded_height=720                                  
closed_captions=0                                 
has_b_frames=0                                    
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A                           
display_aspect_ratio=N/A                          
pix_fmt=yuv444p                                   
level=31                                          
color_range=unknown                               
color_space=unknown                               
color_transfer=unknown                            
color_primaries=unknown                           
chroma_location=left                              
field_order=progressive                           
timecode=N/A                                      
refs=1                                            
is_avc=false                                      
nal_length_size=0                                 
id=0x100                                          
r_frame_rate=20/1                                 
avg_frame_rate=20/1                               
time_base=1/90000                                 
start_pts=420655500                               
start_time=4673.950000                            
duration_ts=N/A                                   
duration=N/A                                      
bit_rate=N/A                                      
max_bit_rate=N/A                                  
bits_per_raw_sample=8                             
nb_frames=N/A                                     
nb_read_frames=N/A                                
nb_read_packets=N/A                               
DISPOSITION:default=0                             
DISPOSITION:dub=0                                 
DISPOSITION:original=0                            
DISPOSITION:comment=0                             
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0                              
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0                             
DISPOSITION:forced=0                              
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0                    
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0                     
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0                       
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0                        
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0                    
[/STREAM]                                         
[FORMAT]                                          
filename=udp://127.0.0.1:10000                    
nb_streams=1                                      
nb_programs=1                                     
format_name=mpegts                                
format_long_name=MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)
start_time=4673.950000                            
duration=N/A                                      
size=N/A                                          
bit_rate=N/A                                      
probe_score=50                                    
[/FORMAT]
```